# Schemata survival in genetic algorithm

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm having some problems in solving this exercise about schemata in genetic algorithms. Suppose I have the following situation, where three parents {1101, 0101, 0001} have, respectively, fitness {0.7, 4.3, 3.5} with respect to an unknown fitness function. The question is: which schemata will have the highest survival probability in the case of a maximization problem? The possible answers I had been given are: { ** 01}, {0 *** }, {***1} and {*101}.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general case the schema theorem states that *the schema with above average fitness, short defining length and lower order is more likely to survive*.

For a schema `H`:

- the order `o(H) = number of fixed bit` (e.g. `o({01*0*}) = 3`)
- the defining length `δ(H) = distance between the first and the last fixed bits` (e.g. `δ({*0*10}) = 3`)
- the probability of a gene not being changed is `(1 - p)` where `p` is the mutation probability. So the probability a schema `H` survives under mutation is `S(H) = (1-p) ^ o(H)`

...but this isn't the general case.

Every individual matches the two schemas `{**01}` and `{***1}`.

No matter what parent is selected for crossover / copy (these operations are fitness-dependent), children will match (at least before mutation) both schemas (with 100% probability).

Assuming mutation is applied gene by gene, for a schema `H` to survive, all fixed bits must remain unchanged. So `{***1}` is more likely to survive (has lower order).